# How can I find the name of the user and set current time in an MVC 3 Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set the name of my user as follows:

```
_testEdit.Test.CreatedBy = Context.User.Identity.Name
_testEdit.Test.Created = now();
```

Seems that the controller has no knowledge of Context and no knowledge of now().

Does anyone know how I can set the user name and the current time (into a datetime field).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this:

```
_testEdit.Test.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
_testEdit.Test.Created = DateTime.Now;
```

Controller has a `User` property so no requirements to use `Context`. For the current date/time use the static getter from `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks very much this works good. I think I will accept this answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Form authentication and you will log in, then HttpContext.User.Identity.Name (you could use just User.Identity.Name) will always be filled.

To get current time user DateTime.Now